# Will a rest api drain server resources

Tags: mysql

I have a 10GB sql dbase and want to provide access to that data to a mobile app using a rest api.The mobile app will be used by less than 100 users.  My DB is a bit sluggish as it was not built for so much data, but has grown over the years. My question is: Will the rest api create more burden for my DB?

Comment: if more people use it, then probably. The fact it's an API or not isn't particularly relevant to that. If you have more users accessing the webserver and database at once then, if your hardware starts to reach the limits of its resources, then potentially you get performance problems. We don't really have enough info to answer the question in detail. P.S. if the DB has grown sluggish, you should investigate whether query optimisations, indexing etc might help it.

Answer (score 1):

Rest Api isn't gonna create any burden on DB if it's normal client, server things.

Let me give a quick example how's rest api works.

Client<---(REST API protocol)----->server<-----(Do query optimization to improve performance of your db and similar kind of optimization)------>db

So before Rest Api, server used to keep some data of client mostly known as session data. But it was creating a burden for server as more memory use and also it was dependent on states of user in somewhat way. mean to do certain operations user has to follow a certain steps before.

But in rest api architecture, every method/call is independent of previous call.
so basically REST architecture is an another  design to communicate between 2 or more (services , clients whatever ).

So I don't see that rest api is gonna affect your db. (though again it depends on your product/service architecture design and developers quality etc.)